# Dozer mapper singleton instance with Spring IOC

Tags: java, spring, singleton, dozer

Inside a web application, I'm using dozer mapper (5.3.2) to perform some object to object mappings.

DozerBeanMapper is instantiated using spring bean definition. Mapping file is provided as property in the spring context xml.

```
<bean id="idmToBoMPersonMapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper" lazy-init="false" scope="singleton" >
    <property name="mappingFiles" value="config/IiIdmToBoMPersonMapping.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Mapping is working, but according to logs, instance of DozerBeanMapper is created every time the code uses the mapper.

```
INFO DozerBeanMapper:166 - Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
```

This is concerns me, I'd expect the mapper to be created once and only once.

I have tried to explicitly use scope="singleton" in the spring bean configuration, but that is not helping either.

Any suggestions for me to try?

Comment: And how do you use the mapper in a way that generates that INFO log message?

Comment: @Andrei Stefan - I'm just using Log4j ConsoleAppender with rootLogger level INFO

Comment: What I meant to find out is, as you said "every time the code uses the mapper", what is that code? How do you make the mapper to "initialize" itself again and again?

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I have few JAX-RS services. All of them have a mapper instance injected using Autowire. For any JAX-RS service invocation, I get this INFO log.

Comment: That's weird. The behavior sounds like you are using that mapper as a prototype instance, not singleton. Or you are not injecting in those services the mapper you showed us or the one you think you are injecting. Are you manually (using `new`) creating those mappers that you inject in services? Can you show the code that does the injection?

Comment: @AndreiStefan double checked, there is no new, it's injection. <code>@Autowired
 private Mapper idmToBoMPersonMapper; </code>

Comment: Maybe enable DEBUG logging in your app and provide a complete log file after testing the scenario. Use pastebin.com for the log.

Answer (score 1):

I would be better to use the Spring integration with Dozer instead, namely the DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean, see [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/springintegration.html) the documentation for further details:

```
   <bean class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mappingFiles" 
                  value="classpath*:/*mapping.xml"/>
        <property name="customConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class=
                      "org.dozer.converters.CustomConverter"/>      
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="eventListeners">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.dozer.listeners.EventListener"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="factories">
            <map>
                <entry key="id" value-ref="bean-factory-ref"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this and see if this helps in avoiding repeated instatiation.

Comment: I tried this, no luck. Perhaps, more analysis on this is hinting towards Spring IOC scope="singleton" is not working period. Not sure though, yet to try with some debug statements in constructors.